# Java decompiled code

Tags: java, arrays, this, decompiling, decompiler

I just decompiled some java code and found something like that

```
public class Example {
    private static String test(String s) {
        String[] test = new String[1];

        ExampleObject exampleObject = new ExampleObject() {
            public void testMethod1() {
                Example.this[0] = "1";//what's that?
            }

            public void testMethod2() {
                Example.this[0] = "2";//what's that?
            }
        };

        //some code with exampleObject and s

        return test[0];
    }
}
```

I don't want to post the original decompiled code, because I don't know if I am allowed to. But this is in principle the same code. There are no super classes and no fields in the original decompiled code.

I know that I can do `Example.this` to access the fields and methods of the current instance of `Example`. But I have never seen a code like `Example.this[0]`. Also `String[] test` is not a field of `Example`, it's a variable in the `private static String test(String s)` method. I tried to compile that code with eclipse, but I get errors.

Edit: The question is what does that code do? Or is it a bug of the decompiler?

Comment: Are you sure it says `Example.this[0]` and not `Example.this.something[0]`?

Comment: Yes I am sure, that's the reason why I am wondering

Comment: And I am pretty sure that `Example.this[0]` should modify the `String[] test`, otherwise the code wouldn't make sense.

Comment: What's the reason for the down vote? What can/should I make better (for my next question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the decompiler. Use a better decompiler. Have you tried [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) or [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau/)?

Comment: No, I downloaded the decompiler anywhere a long time ago. I don't even know the name of the decompiler. It's called "Java Decompiler" but I had never problems with that decampiler. I will try it with one of the decompiler you proposed and report the result. Thank you!

Comment: I tried it with another decompiler and now `Example.this[0]` is replaced with `val$test[0]`. So it was a bug of the decompiler